# remove new line characters from txt file using php

Tags: php, newline, text-files

I have txt file its content like this

```
Hello  
World   
John  
play  
football
```

I want to delete the new line character when reading this text file, but I don't know how it look like
the file .txt and its encoding is utf-8

Comment: Mira, do you want the replaced with nothing, or with some other kind of whitespace?

Answer (score 20):

Just use `file` function with `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` flag.

The `file` reads a whole file and returns an array contains all of the file lines.

Each line contains new line character at their end as default, but we can enforce trimming by `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` flag.

So it will be simply:

```
$lines = file('file.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

The result should be:

```
var_dump($lines);
array(5) {
    [0] => string(5) "Hello"
    [1] => string(5) "World"
    [2] => string(4) "John"
    [3] => string(4) "play"
    [4] => string(8) "football"
}
```

Comment: You can also use this: `$lines = file('file.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES)`. This way you skip empty new lines as well!

Answer (score 14):

There are different kind of newlines. This will remove all 3 kinds in `$string`:

```
$string = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', $string)
```

Comment: are there 2 kinds or 3 kinds ?

Comment: @Mira, 3 kinds (`\r`, `\n`, and `\r\n`) and the script in my answer takes care of the 3.

Answer (score 6):

If your going to be putting the lines into an array, an assuming a reasonable file size you could try something like this.

```
$file = 'newline.txt';      
$data = file_get_contents($file);   
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $data);  

/** Output would look like this

Array
(
    [0] => Hello  
    [1] => World   
    [2] => John  
    [3] => play  
    [4] => football  
)

*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I note that the way it was pasted in the question, this text file appears to have space characters at the end of each line.  I'll assume that was accidental.

```
<?php

// Ooen the file
$fh = fopen("file.txt", "r");

// Whitespace between words (this can be blank, or anything you want)
$divider = " ";

// Read each line from the file, adding it to an output string
$output = "";
while ($line = fgets($fh, 40)) {
  $output .= $divider . trim($line);
}
fclose($fh);

// Trim off opening divider
$output=substr($output,1);

// Print our result
print $output . "\n";
```

Comment: Result will be invalid when any of the word will have more than 40 bytes (not to mention it would work only for single words per line) `trim` is not a good option if - will be sufficient to use rtrim  (You need only to trim the right side) - don't forget about the second argument which is a character mask. As default it will trim: spaces, tabs, new lines, carriage return, null-byte and vertical tabs.

Answer (score 0):

For PHP's [`file()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) function, the `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` flag is the way to go. In case you get your array in another way, like with [`gzfile()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzfile.php), do this:

```
// file.txt
$lines = file('file.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

// file.txt.gz
$lines = gzfile('file.txt.gz');
$lines = array_map(function($e) { return rtrim($e, "\n\r"); }, $lines);
```