# remove new line from txt file after insert value

Tags: php, arrays, newline

i create a txt file from a folder in that way:

```
$fp = fopen("mylist.txt","rw+");
foreach(glob("folder/*.*") as $value){
fwrite($fp,$value."\n");
}
```

and it create inside the txt each items, one per line, BUT it also add a newline at the end of the file.

This is the content of mylist.txt:

```
foldelr/file1.mp3
folder/file2.mp3
(BLANK NEWLINE)
```

I tried to remove the blank newline at the end of the txt file, in this way:

```
$filetxt = fopen("mylist.txt","r");
$rtrim = rtrim($filetxt, "\n");
$newfile = file_put_contents("newfile.txt", $rtrim);
```

But it doesn't work, because in the "newfile.txt", i still have the newline blank after last file name.

I tried to convert file in array, use "array_diff()" to remove the last line, but it fail.
I tried also all the suggestions in this thread: [remove new line characters from txt file using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9926277/remove-new-line-characters-from-txt-file-using-php?rq=1) but not fix my problem.

Does anyone can please help me to understand what i'm missing or mistaken?

Kind Regards

Brus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use file_get_contents method  it works fine for me**

```
    $fp = fopen("mylist.txt","rw+");
    foreach (glob("test/*.*") as $value) {
        fwrite($fp, $value . "\n");
    }

    $filetxt = file_get_contents("mylist.txt");
    $rtrim =  rtrim($filetxt, "\n");
    $newfile = file_put_contents("mylist.txt", $rtrim);
```

**Or You can also remove the last newline by using the array count.**

```
$fp = fopen("mylist.txt","rw+");
$i =0;
foreach(glob("folder/*.*") as $value){
  $i++;
  if($i < count(glob("folder/*.*"))) 
    fwrite($fp,$value."\n");
  else 
    fwrite($fp,$value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to first write new line and only than value (assuming you already have content in file)?

```
fp = fopen("mylist.txt","rw+");

foreach(glob("folder/*.*") as $value){
    fwrite($fp, "\n".$value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that fix another problem.